# Regarding Auto backuping QNAP

Tags: samba

I found this from my putty command and im the new IT here after 2weeks ago before the last IT resigned. The QNAP Backup did not work after 2 weeks and i found this command. can someone explaine what is this ? and how can i check the logs or status why my Qnap is not working for auto backup.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please don't post text as image, rather copy the command as text and format as code.

Answer (score 0):

That mounts the internal ip address 192.168.1.251, and the directory backupserver on there to /readablebd/backupserver/  with the given username and password.

That is likely a writable Blu-ray drive.

If that is the case when it is NOT mounted the backup probably was stored on the server itself at directory /readablebd/backupserver/.

Comment: can i ask cause my password have < is this affect ?? to command should i use /< ??

Comment: This `\<` or quote the whole thing `-o 'username=some<user,password=some<password'`

Comment: Don't use special characters in passwords. If you have a < in there I would assume some commands to fail. What happens after you execute that command. If the < is a problem ... you likely need quotes around the content of the `-o`.